# Find the largest element of an array in c++

Tags: c++, c++11

there is an array containing elements from 1 to 10 and any of the element can be repeat you have to find the index of the largest element.
if there is more than 2 similar largest elements then show the smallest index of those elements.
like [2,2,1,0,0]
then you will print 0.

Comment: How about [`std::max_element()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element)?

Comment: Yep, just look at the standard library.

Comment: This is not a place to just copy/paste homework. you have to show us what you have tried and what problems you are facing.

Comment: First solve the problem of finding the largest number. Then add the feature of remembering where it was.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is obviously an assigned homework exercise.  There is no evidence of effort to do the exercise, beyond copying and pasting it here.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    while(1){
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    multimap<int, int> m;
    int num;
    for(int i=1; i<=n; i++)
    {
        cin>>num;
        m.insert({num,i});
    }
    int capacity = 5;
    int arr[capacity];
    for(int i=0; i<capacity; i++){
        arr[i] = m.count(i+1);
        cout<<i<<" is :\t"<<arr[i]<<"times\n";
    }
    int a;
    a = max_element(arr,arr+capacity)-arr;//it was my doubt section
    cout<<a+1;
    }
}
```

Comment: guys this is my code and i was facing the problem in the last section of my code.I applogize that i am not mention my doubt section at the time of asking the question from you.

Comment: If the code above is suposed to be an answer then please [edit] it and appen the text of the comment as part of the answer.